# Ordering product listing by delivery time - seems too complicated with so many conditions

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database, where I have a table for products and a table for importers of the products. I've been doing sorting system on my product listing page, sorting by name, price and releasedate has not been a problem for me. But now I would like to also add sorting by delivery time. And that's a bit complicated, because delivery times depends on few different things. Here are the necessary fields of my two tables, that can enlighten my situation a bit:

```
products:

    quantity
    status
    importer (id of product importer)


importers:

    id
    deliveryMin
    deliveryMax
```

And the delivery situations from the fastest to the slowest:

1. If product quantity is greater than 0, that means we have it in stock and delivery time is 1-2 days. On that situation the delivery is the fastest.
2. If quantity is 0, we have to look for importers delivery times. Before that - status must be checked. So: if status is 1, the importer (marked in the products table in every product row) has it in stock, and then we must look at the importers table for deliveryMin and deliveryMax. Different importers may have different deliveryMin and deliveryMax, and that should be somehow looked too. Because products, which have status 1, can still have different delivery times and those must be sorted too.
3. If quantity is 0 and product status is 2, that means, that we don't have it in stock, and neither has any of the importers that product in stock. That's the slowest delivery option, 7-14 days.

Is this way too complicated to perform as a MySQL query? How to ORDER BY delivery time when there isn't simply a field for that, but the information must be acquired using so many steps.

This was really easy to code with PHP on viewing the product page, because there is then only one product and you don't have to compare it to anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems to me that Product belongs to Importer (one product can't have more than one importer, is it right?). So:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT products.*,
    IF(quantity > 0, 1, IF(status=2, 7, importers.deliveryMin)) as delivery_min,
    IF(quantity > 0, 2, IF(status=2, 14, importers.deliveryMax)) as delivery_max
    FROM products LEFT JOIN importers ON
    products.importer = importers.id
) as product_delivery
ORDER BY delivery_max
```